# How to extract values from key/value object array in TRINO and create comma separated array of the values

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Working in Trino (aka Presto). I have a table of data that's structured like so:

| company_id | company_name | related_companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xy12345 | Cool Company | [{company_id=we23456,type=PARTNER},{company_id=tr45678, type=PARTNER},{company_id=fu76354,type=PARTNER}] |

The `related_companies` field is of type `list<struct<company_id: string, type: string>>`

**How can I structure my query to get the output to result in:**

| company_id | company_name | related_companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xy12345 | Cool Company | we23456, tr45678, fu76354 |

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage [array functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) - `transform` and `array_join`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset (company_id, company_name, related_companies) as (
    values ('xy12345', 'Cool Company', array[cast(row('we23456','PARTNER') as row(company_id varchar, "type" varchar)), 
                                            cast(row('tr45678','PARTNER') as row(company_id varchar, "type" varchar))])
)

-- query
select company_id, 
   company_name, 
   array_join(transform(related_companies, r -> r.company_id), ', ') related_companies
from dataset;
```

Output:

| company_id | company_name | related_companies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xy12345 | Cool Company | we23456, tr45678 |